# android scanning all .mp3 files in SD Card

Tags: android, media

I'm trying to scan all .mp3 files in my SD card and save its name. 
here is a fragment of code which is responsible for that. 
1.What i'm doing wrong?
 1. Which is correct path for SD Card /mnt/sdcard or /sdcard ?

```
public class PlayerActivity extends Activity
{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.player_activity); 
    }
    public class SongsManager 
    {
        // SDCard Path
        //final String MEDIA_PATH = new String(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri("external").toString());
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        public SongsManager()
        {

        }

        public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList()
        {
         //   File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
            File home = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

            if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) 
            {

                for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) 
                {
                    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                    song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                    // Adding each song to SongList
                    songsList.add(song);

                }
            }
            // return songs list array
            return songsList;

        }


        class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter 
        {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) 
            {
                return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I seem to recollect that there's a bug in the Nexus 7 among other devices which breaks `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` while connected via adb. What device are you using? What happens when you run the code above? What doesn't work?

Comment: I'm using galaxy Ace. 
Problem is nothing happens when i run the code. 
I've also tried to set home path \mnt\sdcard but it doesn't work too.

Comment: I'm developing on a Nexus 7 and I haven't seen any problems using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

Answer (score 5):

try this code snippet

```
final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getPath() + "/";
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private String mp3Pattern = ".mp3";

// Constructor
public SongsManager() {

}

/**
 * Function to read all mp3 files and store the details in
 * ArrayList
 * */
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() {
    System.out.println(MEDIA_PATH);
    if (MEDIA_PATH != null) {
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
        File[] listFiles = home.listFiles();
        if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
            for (File file : listFiles) {
                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    scanDirectory(file);
                } else {
                    addSongToList(file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // return songs list array
    return songsList;
}

private void scanDirectory(File directory) {
    if (directory != null) {
        File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();
        if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
            for (File file : listFiles) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    scanDirectory(file);
                } else {
                    addSongToList(file);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

private void addSongToList(File song) {
    if (song.getName().endsWith(mp3Pattern)) {
        HashMap<String, String> songMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        songMap.put("songTitle",
                song.getName().substring(0, (song.getName().length() - 4)));
        songMap.put("songPath", song.getPath());

        // Adding each song to SongList
        songsList.add(songMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: THe code is fine , but its loading files of external sd card , its just fetching internal phone memory files,anyways thanks

Comment: Thanks +1 for saving my day! and loved your website! and idea also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's wrong in your code. But you can give this approach a try:

```
public HashMap<String, String> scanDirectory(File dir) {

HashMap<String, String> song; 
String mp3Pattern = ".mp3";
File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();

if (listFile != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

        if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
            walkdir(listFile[i]);
        } else {
          if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(mp3Pattern)){
               song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                // Adding each song to SongList
                songsList.add(song);

          }
        }
    }
}  
   return song;
  }
```

To scan entire whole sdcard for mp3 call `scanDirectory(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());`

Comment: the problem is that this code is don't scan the whole sdcard.

Comment: Did you use : `scanDirectory(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())` ?

Answer (score 0):

The `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()` is usually of the form 
"/storage/emulated/0/" or so.

You split this to get the root -

```
String media_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
String[] splitPath= media_path .split("/");
final String MEDIA_PATH = "/" + splitPath[1] + "/";
```

This works!

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with what android consider as external storage. It is not always the sd card that you add to your device. the internal memory can also be external storage. /sdcard or /mnt/sdcard is the same location and it may point to your internal storage. so you have to scan the /mnt folder completely. like in some device /mnt/sdcard will be internal memory and
/mnt/extSdCard will be the one you have added. 
            File home = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
this method will return the first external storage and not all.

Answer (score -2):

try this:
    final String MEDIA_PATH = "/storage/";

Comment: You shouldn't use hardcoded paths for anything, because they will work only on some devices.