# Getting audio files from storage

Tags: android, cursor, mp3, android-mediaplayer, mediastore

I am trying to get all the audio files from device both internal and external storage .so i am using mediastorage and cursor .But I am not able to get any proper example of song retrieval.

I used this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
Cursor cursor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String[] columns = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID };
    int[] displayViews = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
    cursor = cr.query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,columns, null, null, null);
    setListAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cursor,columns,displayViews,1));
}

public static ArrayList<SongDto> getMusicInfos(Context context) {

    ArrayList<SongDto> musicInfos = new ArrayList<SongDto>();

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
        cursor.moveToNext();


        int isMusic = cursor.getInt(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC));

        if (isMusic != 0) {
            SongDto music = new SongDto();


            music.path = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));

            if (!new File(music.path).exists()) {
                continue;
            }


            music.songId = cursor.getLong(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));

            music.songTitle = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));


            music.songTitle = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));


            music.album = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));


            music.songArtist = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));

            music.duration = cursor
                    .getLong(cursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION));

            MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            mmr.setDataSource(music.path);
            mmr.release();

            musicInfos.add(music);
        }
    }

    return musicInfos;
}
}
```

and

```
public class SongDto {

public long songId;
public String songTitle;
public String songArtist;
public String path;
public short genre;
public long duration;
public String album;
public Bitmap albumArt;

public String toString() {
    return String.format("songId: %d, Title: %s, Artist: %s, Path: %s, Genere: %d, Duration %s",
            songId, songTitle, songArtist, path, genre, duration);
}
}
```

and i am getting a run time error I fixed the SimpleCursorAdapter as it is deprecated how to get the song and what wrong I am doing in setting the adapter,any example or hint will be helpful.

Comment: You might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18268013/5067493) helpful.

Comment: I m able to get the song from a fixed folder but i want to get all song which is possible through mediastore only other way will to complex

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like that (kotlin) :

```
    //fetch the audio files from storage
    val contentResolver = this.contentResolver
    val uri: Uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    val cursor: Cursor? = contentResolver?.query(uri, null, null, null, null)

    //looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            val title: String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE))
            val artist: String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST))
            val duration: String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION))
            val url: String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA))
            val modelAudio = ModelAudio()
            modelAudio.setaudioTitle(title)
            modelAudio.setaudioArtist(artist)
            modelAudio.setaudioUri(url)
            modelAudio.setaudioDuration(duration)
            audioArrayList.add(modelAudio)
        } while (cursor.moveToNext())
    }
```

In manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Checking permission (dexter):

```
   private fun checkPermissions() {
   Dexter.withActivity(this).withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .withListener(object : PermissionListener {
                override fun onPermissionGranted(permissionGrantedResponse: PermissionGrantedResponse) {
                }
                override fun onPermissionDenied(permissionDeniedResponse: PermissionDeniedResponse) {}
                override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                        permissionRequest: PermissionRequest,
                        permissionToken: PermissionToken
                ) {
                    // asking for permission
                    permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest()
                }
            }).check()
}
```

Dependency :)

```
  implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a file browser if you like. You can find file browser and folder browser implementation in the following example.
[Link](https://bitbucket.org/saeed1/file-browser-android)

Comment: I am working in a media player .if I go through each and every file it will take more time to get the audio file in the device so I need to go through the mediastore and cursor way so in this way i will be able to get all the media details like album art,artist etc.