# Downloading multiple videos with progress bar

Tags: android, download

Hy. I am developing an Android application where I am downloading videos from server. I have no issue in downloading multiple videos concurrently and saving them in sdcard. I am using DownloadManager Class for downloading. I can see a downloading icon in status bar and download progress in notification area and it is manage by DownloadManger itself. I have a separate tab name Downloads where I am using a listview to show previously downloaded videos but now I also has to show the currently downloading videos with progressbar. My problems are 
1 - how to get those videos which are currently downloading to show in listview
2 - How to maintain progressbar for all videos.

This is my current code

```
String urlDownload = "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/ex4clsfmiu142dy/test.zip?token_hash=AAGD-XcBL8C3flflkmxjbzdr7_2W_i6CZ_3rM5zQpUCYaw&dl=1";
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(urlDownload));

    request.setDescription("Testando");
    request.setTitle("Download");
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "teste.zip");

    final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

    final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);

    final ProgressBar mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            boolean downloading = true;

            while (downloading) {

                DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
                q.setFilterById(downloadId);

                Cursor cursor = manager.query(q);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int bytes_downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                int bytes_total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));

                if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                    downloading = false;
                }

               final int dl_progress = (int) ((double)bytes_downloaded / (double)bytes_total * 100f);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        mProgressBar.setProgress((int) dl_progress);

                    }
                });

                Log.d(Constants.MAIN_VIEW_ACTIVITY, statusMessage(cursor));
                cursor.close();
            }

        }
    }).start();
```

A image is attached to show what I want to achieve. Any help will be apreciated. Thanks
[image]

Comment: post the code you have currently

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show all video from your card or storage you can refer hare
[android scanning all .mp3 files in SD Card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080880/android-scanning-all-mp3-files-in-sd-card)
and for current video you have to store current video in any any sql or shared preference file you can get name from there when finished remove from satellite or shared preference

Comment: But how to show progress bar on videos after getting from shared preference